# UIView - custom view - Where does the view's subviews is initialized?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm create a custom UIView with some sub views.
In the IB - i'v set my subview to be a CreateAlbumView which is a UIView, and created some subviews and outlet those.

When i'm inflating this view in code, and adding it to a super view the follow code is being called:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
        [self setViews];
    return self;
}
```

but the subviews are all nil there - making my setViews() function to become useless.

I've changed my code to set the code in the following function, but it doesn't seems right:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setViews];
}
```

Where does the subviews are actually initialized and where can i start using them ?

Comment: Don't, **ever**, add subviews inside `-layoutSubviews` (unless you are writing a custom table view).

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
```

The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives an awakeFromNib message, **it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established**.

Comment: i've done it but it's actually getting called more than once. why is that ?

Comment: Is it called on same objects? Try logging self, NSLog(@"self = %@", self);.

Answer (score 1):

> I've changed my code to set the code in `layoutSubviews`, but it
>   doesn't seems right.

— well, have a method create the views (`setViews` is a bad name due to cocoa conventions) and layout them and add them in `layoutSubviews`, than `layoutSubviews` does exactly what it's name suggests.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder 
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
        [self createSubviews];
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *v in mySubviews) {
        v.frame = CGRectMake(...);
        [self addSubview:v];
    }
}
```